# How to access any environment variable like %HOMEPATH% in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, environment-variables

Basically in my sql script , I want to create a database [DATABASE_NAME] by providing an explicit location to store its .mdf file? But the problem is, I must create the .mdf file in %HOMEPATH% directory i.e. C:/users/[username] and I cannot find a way to read an environment variable in sql. Is there any way I can write the script as

```
CREATE DATABASE [DATABASENAME] ON PRIMARY (NAME = 'DatabaseName',
FILENAME = '%HOMEPATH%\DatabaseName.mdf'
```

Comment: may be that the answer that you are waiting for, result irrelevant, as `[username]` will result in the account that is running sqlserver service

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `sqlcmd` to run your script, you can use environment variables as follows:

```
CREATE DATABASE [DATABASENAME] ON PRIMARY (NAME = 'DatabaseName',
FILENAME = '$(HOMEDRIVE)$(HOMEPATH)\DatabaseName.mdf')
```

The `HOMEPATH` environment variable does not include the drive letter; `HOMEDRIVE` specifies that. Or you can use `$(USERPROFILE)` which includes both.

Note that the SQL Server service is unlikely to have the correct access rights to write to that location, so it is likely to fail with an Access Denied error (operating system error 5).

Answer (score -1):

that's because of the slashes, you should try to use a backslash instead  your Directory would then be `HOMEPATH/DatabaseName.mdf`

Comment: SQL Server's documentation does not specify the directory separators, however the convention on Windows is to use backslashes: \. My experiment on SQL Server 2008 R2 indicates that the first directory separator, after the drive letter, must be a backslash \ but forward slashes / are permitted after that. In this instance it makes no difference - your answer does not solve the problem.